# Actors at a very deep level, what makes them unique?

Tags: multithreading, akka, actor

I'm not strong in multi-threading programming. And I've been working with akka pretty much enough, but nonetheless I still don't understand what makes actors and akka so neat, convenient, safe and so and so forth. I know that they receive messages, an actor can receive only message at a time. But what of it, what makes them thread-safe?

First of all, actors are just a library built on system threads that involves using shared mutable state and they need somehow to deal with it.

So the question is, how do actors work at a very deep level? I'd also appreciate any link about it.

Comment: Akka sources are open, did you try to look at them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Björn's answer hits the important point: The actor model encapsulates state and any logic that operates on that state in an actor. The only way to change state from the outside is to send the actor a message.

Because only the actor can modify the state, and because it processes messages serially, there's no possibility of concurrent modification. No race conditions.

Ryan Tanner (disclosure: Ryan works at my company) has a great blog post about what makes actors special: http://blog.goconspire.com/post/64274254800/akka-at-conspire-part-2-why-we-like-actors.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up the [Actor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) with one concrete implementation of it in [Akka](http://akka.io).

The code inside a single actor is only run on one thread at any given time processing one single message at any given time. If your actors don't share mutable objects between each other and only communicate via immutable messages then the code is free of the kind of races where you inadvertently change the same object/variable from multiple threads concurrently.

How the implementation runs your actors on top of multiple threads should be irrelevant. But you are of course free to look at the [Akka source code.](https://github.com/akka/akka)